# Google AdSense review keeps returning with NO CONTENT error (JavaScript client-side rendered)

Tags: javascript, html, adsense, client-side-scripting

The Google AdSense review keeps returning with a **NO CONTENT** error. It is a JavaScript website, which is fully rendered client side, which means that it does not have any static content in the body.

This is my index.html page:

```
​​    <html>
        <head>
            <script data-ad-client="***GoogleAdSenseID***" async
                src="https://pagead​2...adsbygoogle.js">
            </script>
        </head>
        <body>
        </body>
        <script src="js/myscript.js"></script> 
    </html>
```

How do I overcome this? TIA.